# How can i apply different Defs to different variables using loop or some other way in python?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have 90 user define functions and i need to apply these functions to 90 different variables. i can do that by writing 90 lines of code but i want to do that in few lines or efficient way. my sample code for 2 variables and 2 functions.

My code: -

```
def PCT_ADLT_MALE(PCT_ADLT_MALE):
    if 0 <= PCT_ADLT_MALE <= 38:
        label = "B   [0]-{38}"
    elif 39 <= PCT_ADLT_MALE <= 44:
        label = "B   [39]-{44}"
    elif 45 <= PCT_ADLT_MALE <= 48:
        label = "B   [45]-{48}"
    elif 49 <= PCT_ADLT_MALE <= 51:
        label = "B   [49]-{51}"
    elif 52 <= PCT_ADLT_MALE <= 53:
        label = "B   [52]-{53}"
    elif 54 <= PCT_ADLT_MALE <= 100:
        label = "B   [54]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label

def PCT_ADLT_FEM(PCT_ADLT_FEM):
    if 0 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 40:
        label = "B   [0]-{40}"
    elif 41 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 45:
        label = "B   [41]-{45}"
    elif 46 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 47:
        label = "B   [46]-{47}"
    elif 48 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 48:
        label = "B   [48]-{48}"
    elif 49 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 49:
        label = "B   [49]-{49}"
    elif 50 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 50:
        label = "B   [50]-{50}"
    elif 51 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 51:
        label = "B   [51]-{51}"
    elif 52 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 52:
        label = "B   [52]-{52}"
    elif 53 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 53:
        label = "B   [53]-{53}"
    elif 54 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 55:
        label = "B   [54]-{55}"
    elif 56 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 57:
        label = "B   [56]-{57}"
    elif 58 <= PCT_ADLT_FEM <= 100:
        label = "B   [58]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label

def PCT_HOME_VAL_300_TO_350K(PCT_HOME_VAL_300_TO_350K):
    if 0 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_300_TO_350K <= 5:
        label = "B   [0]-{5}"
    elif 6 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_300_TO_350K <= 10:
        label = "B   [6]-{10}"
    elif 11 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_300_TO_350K <= 100:
        label = "B   [11]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label


def PCT_HOME_VAL_800_TO_1M(PCT_HOME_VAL_800_TO_1M):
    if 0 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_800_TO_1M <= 1:
        label = "B   [0]-{1}"
    elif 2 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_800_TO_1M <= 100:
        label = "B   [2]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label


def PCT_INC_175_TO_200K(PCT_INC_175_TO_200K):
    if 0 <= PCT_INC_175_TO_200K <= 2:
        label = "B   [0]-{2}"
    elif 3 <= PCT_INC_175_TO_200K <= 4:
        label = "B   [3]-{4}"
    elif 5 <= PCT_INC_175_TO_200K <= 8:
        label = "B   [5]-{8}"
    elif 9 <= PCT_INC_175_TO_200K <= 10:
        label = "B   [9]-{10}"
    elif 11 <= PCT_INC_175_TO_200K <= 100:
        label = "B   [11]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label

def PCT_INC_OVER_250K(PCT_INC_OVER_250K):
    if 0 <= PCT_INC_OVER_250K <= 1:
        label = "B   [0]-{1}"
    elif 2 <= PCT_INC_OVER_250K <= 4:
        label = "B   [2]-{4}"
    elif 5 <= PCT_INC_OVER_250K <= 100:
        label = "B   [5]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label



def PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER(PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER):
    if 0 <= PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER <= 4:
        label = "B   [0]-{4}"
    elif 5 <= PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER <= 11:
        label = "B   [5]-{11}"
    elif 12 <= PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER <= 26:
        label = "B   [12]-{26}"
    elif 27 <= PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER <= 51:
        label = "B   [27]-{51}"
    elif 52 <= PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER <= 68:
        label = "B   [52]-{68}"
    elif 69 <= PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER <= 100:
        label = "B   [69]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label



def PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K(PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K):
    if 0 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K <= 6:
        label = "B   [0]-{6}"
    elif 7 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K <= 14:
        label = "B   [7]-{14}"
    elif 15 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K <= 26:
        label = "B   [15]-{26}"
    elif 27 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K <= 37:
        label = "B   [27]-{37}"
    elif 38 <= PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K <= 100:
        label = "B   [38]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label




def PCT_INC_100_TO_125K(PCT_INC_100_TO_125K):
    if 0 <= PCT_INC_100_TO_125K <= 3:
        label = "B   [0]-{3}"
    elif 4 <= PCT_INC_100_TO_125K <= 6:
        label = "B   [4]-{6}"
    elif 7 <= PCT_INC_100_TO_125K <= 9:
        label = "B   [7]-{9}"
    elif 10 <= PCT_INC_100_TO_125K <= 11:
        label = "B   [10]-{11}"
    elif 12 <= PCT_INC_100_TO_125K <= 14:
        label = "B   [12]-{14}"
    elif 15 <= PCT_INC_100_TO_125K <= 16:
        label = "B   [15]-{16}"
    elif 17 <= PCT_INC_100_TO_125K <= 100:
        label = "B   [17]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label





def PCT_GRADUATE_EDU(PCT_GRADUATE_EDU):
    if 0 <= PCT_GRADUATE_EDU <= 2:
        label = "B   [0]-{2}"
    elif 3 <= PCT_GRADUATE_EDU <= 5:
        label = "B   [3]-{5}"
    elif 6 <= PCT_GRADUATE_EDU <= 7:
        label = "B   [6]-{7}"
    elif 8 <= PCT_GRADUATE_EDU <= 9:
        label = "B   [9]-{9}"
    elif 10 <= PCT_GRADUATE_EDU <= 100:
        label = "B   [10]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label


def PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR):
    if 0 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 2:
        label = "B   [0]-{2}"
    elif 3 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 7:
        label = "B   [3]-{7}"
    elif 8 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 11:
        label = "B   [8]-{11}"
    elif 12 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 14:
        label = "B   [12]-{14}"
    elif 15 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 17:
        label = "B   [15]-{17}"
    elif 18 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 20:
        label = "B   [18]-{20}"
    elif 21 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 23:
        label = "B   [21]-{23}"
    elif 24 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 27:
        label = "B   [24]-{27}"
    elif 28 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 32:
        label = "B   [28]-{32}"
    elif 33 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <= 36:
        label = "B   [33]-{36}"
    elif 37 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR <=100:
        label = "B   [37]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label

def PCT_EDU_DLVRY_ONLY(PCT_EDU_DLVRY_ONLY):
    if 0 <= PCT_EDU_DLVRY_ONLY <= 1:
        label = "B   [0]-{1}"
    elif 2 <= PCT_EDU_DLVRY_ONLY <= 100:
        label = "B   [2]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label

def PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR):
    if 0 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <= 10:
        label = "B   [0]-{10}"
    elif 11 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <= 15:
        label = "B   [11]-{15}"
    elif 16 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <= 18:
        label = "B   [16]-{18}"
    elif 19 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <= 20:
        label = "B   [19]-{20}"
    elif 21 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <= 23:
        label = "B   [21]-{23}"
    elif 24 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <= 26:
        label = "B   [24]-{26}"
    elif 27 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <= 28:
        label = "B   [27]-{28}"
    elif 29 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <= 32:
        label = "B   [29]-{32}"
    elif 33 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <= 36:
        label = "B   [33]-{36}"
    elif 37 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR <=100:
        label = "B   [37]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label


def PCT_E3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT(PCT_E3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT):
    if 0 <= PCT_E3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 4:
        label = "B   [0]-{4}"
    elif 5 <= PCT_E3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 8:
        label = "B   [5]-{8}"
    elif 9 <= PCT_E3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 15:
        label = "B   [9]-{15}"
    elif 16 <= PCT_E3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 100:
        label = "B   [16]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label


def PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR):
    if 0 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR <= 2:
        label = "B   [0]-{2}"
    elif 3 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR <= 5:
        label = "B   [3]-{5}"
    elif 6 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR <= 7:
        label = "B   [6]-{7}"
    elif 8 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR <= 9:
        label = "B   [8]-{9}"
    elif 10 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR <= 14:
        label = "B   [10]-{14}"
    elif 15 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR <= 17:
        label = "B   [15]-{17}"
    elif 18 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR <= 100:
        label = "B   [18]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label


def PCT_E2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT(PCT_E2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT):
    if 0 <= PCT_E2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 4:
        label = "B   [0]-{4}"
    elif 5 <= PCT_E2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 8:
        label = "B   [5]-{8}"
    elif 9 <= PCT_E2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 15:
        label = "B   [9]-{15}"
    elif 16 <= PCT_E2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 20:
        label = "B   [16]-{20}"
    elif 21 <= PCT_E2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 100:
        label = "B   [21]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label



def PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR):
    if 0 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR <= 4:
        label = "B   [0]-{4}"
    elif 5 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR <= 9:
        label = "B   [5]-{9}"
    elif 10 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR <= 11:
        label = "B   [10]-{11}"
    elif 12 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR <= 14:
        label = "B   [12]-{14}"
    elif 15 <= PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR <= 100:
        label = "B   [15]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label



   
def PCT_INC_150_TO_175K(PCT_INC_150_TO_175K):
    if 0 <= PCT_INC_150_TO_175K <= 2:
        label = "B   [0]-{2}"
    elif 3 <= PCT_INC_150_TO_175K <= 4:
        label = "B   [3]-{4}"
    elif 5 <= PCT_INC_150_TO_175K <= 6:
        label = "B   [5]-{6}"
    elif 7 <= PCT_INC_150_TO_175K <= 10:
        label = "B   [7]-{10}"
    elif 11 <= PCT_INC_150_TO_175K <= 12:
        label = "B   [11]-{12}"
    elif 13 <= PCT_INC_150_TO_175K <= 100:
        label = "B   [13]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label


def PCT_D2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT(PCT_D2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT):
    if 0 <= PCT_D2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 2:
        label = "B   [0]-{2}"
    elif 3 <= PCT_D2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 5:
        label = "B   [3]-{5}"
    elif 6 <= PCT_D2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 8:
        label = "B   [6]-{8}"
    elif 9 <= PCT_D2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 11:
        label = "B   [9]-{11}"
    elif 12 <= PCT_D2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 13:
        label = "B   [12]-{13}"
    elif 14 <= PCT_D2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 100:
        label = "B   [14]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label

def PCT_INC_20_TO_30K(PCT_INC_20_TO_30K):
    if 0 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 3:
        label = "B   [0]-{3}"
    elif 4 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 6:
        label = "B   [4]-{6}"
    elif 7 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 8:
        label = "B   [7]-{8}"
    elif 9 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 11:
        label = "B   [9]-{11}"
    elif 12 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 13:
        label = "B   [12]-{13}"
    elif 14 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 15:
        label = "B   [14]-{15}"
    elif 16 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 17:
        label = "B   [16]-{17}"
    elif 18 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 20:
        label = "B   [18]-{20}"
    elif 21 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 23:
        label = "B   [21]-{23}"
    elif 24 <= PCT_INC_20_TO_30K <= 100:
        label = "B   [24]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label

def PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT(PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT):
    if 0 <= PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 3:
        label = "B   [0]-{3}"
    elif 4 <= PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 5:
        label = "B   [4]-{5}"
    elif 6 <= PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 7:
        label = "B   [6]-{7}"
    elif 8 <= PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 9:
        label = "B   [8]-{9}"
    elif 10 <= PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 12:
        label = "B   [10]-{12}"
    elif 13 <= PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 14:
        label = "B   [13]-{14}"
    elif 15 <= PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT <= 100:
        label = "B   [15]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label

def PCT_INC_30_TO_40K(PCT_INC_30_TO_40K):
    if 0 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 2:
        label = "B   [0]-{2}"
    elif 3 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 4:
        label = "B   [3]-{4}"
    elif 5 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 7:
        label = "B   [5]-{7}"
    elif 8 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 9:
        label = "B   [8]-{9}"
    elif 10 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 11:
        label = "B   [10]-{11}"
    elif 12 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 13:
        label = "B   [12]-{13}"
    elif 14 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 15:
        label = "B   [14]-{15}"
    elif 16 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 17:
        label = "B   [16]-{17}"
    elif 18 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 19:
        label = "B   [18]-{19}"
    elif 20 <= PCT_INC_30_TO_40K <= 100:
        label = "B   [20]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label


def PCT_INC_50_TO_75K(PCT_INC_50_TO_75K):
    if 0 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 3:
        label = "B   [0]-{3}"
    elif 4 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 6:
        label = "B   [4]-{6}"
    elif 7 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 11:
        label = "B   [7]-{11}"
    elif 12 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 14:
        label = "B   [12]-{14}"
    elif 15 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 16:
        label = "B   [15]-{16}"
    elif 17 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 18:
        label = "B   [17]-{18}"
    elif 19 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 20:
        label = "B   [19]-{20}"
    elif 21 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 22:
        label = "B   [21]-{22}"
    elif 23 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 24:
        label = "B   [23]-{24}"
    elif 25 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 27:
        label = "B   [25]-{27}"
    elif 28 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 29:
        label = "B   [28]-{29}"
    elif 30 <= PCT_INC_50_TO_75K <= 100:
        label = "B   [30]-{100}"
    else:
        label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
    return label


Test['PCT_ADLT_MALE'] = Test['PCT_ADLT_MALE'].apply(PCT_ADLT_MALE)
Test['PCT_ADLT_FEM'] = Test['PCT_ADLT_FEM'].apply(PCT_ADLT_FEM)
Test['PCT_SINGLE'] = Test['PCT_SINGLE'].apply(PCT_SINGLE)
Test['PCT_MARRIED'] = Test['PCT_MARRIED'].apply(PCT_MARRIED)
Test['PCT_HH_NO_PRESNC_CHILD'] = Test['PCT_HH_NO_PRESNC_CHILD'].apply(PCT_HH_NO_PRESNC_CHILD)
Test['PCT_HH_PRESNC_CHILD'] = Test['PCT_HH_PRESNC_CHILD'].apply(PCT_HH_PRESNC_CHILD)
Test['PCT_SOME_HS_EDU_OR_LESS'] = Test['PCT_SOME_HS_EDU_OR_LESS'].apply(PCT_SOME_HS_EDU_OR_LESS)
Test['PCT_HS_EDU'] = Test['PCT_HS_EDU'].apply(PCT_HS_EDU)
Test['PCT_SOME_COLLG_EDU'] = Test['PCT_SOME_COLLG_EDU'].apply(PCT_SOME_COLLG_EDU)
Test['PCT_COLLG_EDU'] = Test['PCT_COLLG_EDU'].apply(PCT_COLLG_EDU)
Test['PCT_GRADUATE_EDU'] = Test['PCT_GRADUATE_EDU'].apply(PCT_GRADUATE_EDU)
Test['PCT_PRFSSNL_TECH'] = Test['PCT_PRFSSNL_TECH'].apply(PCT_PRFSSNL_TECH)
Test['PCT_MGMT'] = Test['PCT_MGMT'].apply(PCT_MGMT)
Test['PCT_SALES_MKTG'] = Test['PCT_SALES_MKTG'].apply(PCT_SALES_MKTG)
Test['PCT_CLRCL_SVC_WKR'] = Test['PCT_CLRCL_SVC_WKR'].apply(PCT_CLRCL_SVC_WKR)
Test['PCT_TRDSMAN_MACHOPER_LABORER'] = Test['PCT_TRDSMAN_MACHOPER_LABORER'].apply(PCT_TRDSMAN_MACHOPER_LABORER)
Test['PCT_STUDENT'] = Test['PCT_STUDENT'].apply(PCT_STUDENT)
Test['PCT_HOMEMAKER'] = Test['PCT_HOMEMAKER'].apply(PCT_HOMEMAKER)
Test['PCT_RETIRED'] = Test['PCT_RETIRED'].apply(PCT_RETIRED)
Test['PCT_MILITARY_RETIRED'] = Test['PCT_MILITARY_RETIRED'].apply(PCT_MILITARY_RETIRED)
Test['PCT_BUSN_OWNR'] = Test['PCT_BUSN_OWNR'].apply(PCT_BUSN_OWNR)
Test['PCT_INC_BELOW_15K'] = Test['PCT_INC_BELOW_15K'].apply(PCT_INC_BELOW_15K)
Test['PCT_INC_15_TO_20K'] = Test['PCT_INC_15_TO_20K'].apply(PCT_INC_15_TO_20K)
Test['PCT_INC_20_TO_30K'] = Test['PCT_INC_20_TO_30K'].apply(PCT_INC_20_TO_30K)
Test['PCT_INC_30_TO_40K'] = Test['PCT_INC_30_TO_40K'].apply(PCT_INC_30_TO_40K)
Test['PCT_INC_40_TO_50K'] = Test['PCT_INC_40_TO_50K'].apply(PCT_INC_40_TO_50K)
Test['PCT_INC_50_TO_75K'] = Test['PCT_INC_50_TO_75K'].apply(PCT_INC_50_TO_75K)
Test['PCT_INC_75_TO_100K'] = Test['PCT_INC_75_TO_100K'].apply(PCT_INC_75_TO_100K)
Test['PCT_INC_100_TO_125K'] = Test['PCT_INC_100_TO_125K'].apply(PCT_INC_100_TO_125K)
Test['PCT_INC_125_TO_150K'] = Test['PCT_INC_125_TO_150K'].apply(PCT_INC_125_TO_150K)
Test['PCT_INC_150_TO_175K'] = Test['PCT_INC_150_TO_175K'].apply(PCT_INC_150_TO_175K)
Test['PCT_INC_175_TO_200K'] = Test['PCT_INC_175_TO_200K'].apply(PCT_INC_175_TO_200K)
Test['PCT_INC_200_TO_250K'] = Test['PCT_INC_200_TO_250K'].apply(PCT_INC_200_TO_250K)
Test['PCT_INC_OVER_250K'] = Test['PCT_INC_OVER_250K'].apply(PCT_INC_OVER_250K)
Test['PCT_DEFINITE_RENTER'] = Test['PCT_DEFINITE_RENTER'].apply(PCT_DEFINITE_RENTER)
Test['PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER'] = Test['PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER'].apply(PCT_PROBABLE_RENTER)
Test['PCT_PROBABLE_OWNR'] = Test['PCT_PROBABLE_OWNR'].apply(PCT_PROBABLE_OWNR)
Test['PCT_DEFINITE_OWNR'] = Test['PCT_DEFINITE_OWNR'].apply(PCT_DEFINITE_OWNR)
Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_SFDU'] = Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_SFDU'].apply(PCT_DWELL_TYPE_SFDU)
Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_MFDU'] = Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_MFDU'].apply(PCT_DWELL_TYPE_MFDU)
Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_BUSN'] = Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_BUSN'].apply(PCT_DWELL_TYPE_BUSN)
Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_CONDO'] = Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_CONDO'].apply(PCT_DWELL_TYPE_CONDO)
Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_MOBILE_HOME'] = Test['PCT_DWELL_TYPE_MOBILE_HOME'].apply(PCT_DWELL_TYPE_MOBILE_HOME)
Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_0_TO_6_MTHS'] = Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_0_TO_6_MTHS'].apply(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_0_TO_6_MTHS)
Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_7_TO_12_MTHS'] = Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_7_TO_12_MTHS'].apply(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_7_TO_12_MTHS)
Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR'] = Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR'].apply(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_1_TO_2_YR)
Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_3_TO_5_YR'] = Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_3_TO_5_YR'].apply(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_3_TO_5_YR)
Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR'] = Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR'].apply(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_6_TO_10_YR)
Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_11_TO_15_YR'] = Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_11_TO_15_YR'].apply(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_11_TO_15_YR)
Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR'] = Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR'].apply(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_16_TO_20_YR)
Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR'] = Test['PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR'].apply(PCT_RSDNC_LEN_OVER_20_YR)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_BELOW_50K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_BELOW_50K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_BELOW_50K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_50_TO_100K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_100_TO_150K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_100_TO_150K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_100_TO_150K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_150_TO_200K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_150_TO_200K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_150_TO_200K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_200_TO_250K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_200_TO_250K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_200_TO_250K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_250_TO_300K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_250_TO_300K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_250_TO_300K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_300_TO_350K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_300_TO_350K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_300_TO_350K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_350_TO_400K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_350_TO_400K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_350_TO_400K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_400_TO_450K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_400_TO_450K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_400_TO_450K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_450_TO_500K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_450_TO_500K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_450_TO_500K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_500_TO_600K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_500_TO_600K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_500_TO_600K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_600_TO_700K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_600_TO_700K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_600_TO_700K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_700_TO_800K'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_700_TO_800K'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_700_TO_800K)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_800_TO_1M'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_800_TO_1M'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_800_TO_1M)
Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_1M_TO_1HALFM'] = Test['PCT_HOME_VAL_1M_TO_1HALFM'].apply(PCT_HOME_VAL_1M_TO_1HALFM)
Test['PCT_EDU_DLVRY_ONLY'] = Test['PCT_EDU_DLVRY_ONLY'].apply(PCT_EDU_DLVRY_ONLY)
Test['PCT_MAIL_RSPNS_SINGLE_BUYER'] = Test['PCT_MAIL_RSPNS_SINGLE_BUYER'].apply(PCT_MAIL_RSPNS_SINGLE_BUYER)
Test['PCT_NO_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_NO_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_NO_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_1_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_1_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_1_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_2_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_2_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_2_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_3_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_3_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_3_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_4_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_4_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_4_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_5_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_5_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_5_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_6_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_6_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_6_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_7_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_7_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_7_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_8_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_8_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_8_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_9_OPEN_TRDLN'] = Test['PCT_9_OPEN_TRDLN'].apply(PCT_9_OPEN_TRDLN)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_A1'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_A1'].apply(PCT_A1_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_A2'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_A2'].apply(PCT_A2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_B1'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_B1'].apply(PCT_B1_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_B2'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_B2'].apply(PCT_B2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_C1'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_C1'].apply(PCT_C1_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_C2'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_C2'].apply(PCT_C2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_D1'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_D1'].apply(PCT_D1_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_D2'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_D2'].apply(PCT_D2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_D3'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_D3'].apply(PCT_D3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_E1'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_E1'].apply(PCT_E1_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_E2'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_E2'].apply(PCT_E2_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_E3'] = Test['PCT_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT_E3'].apply(PCT_E3_TRGT_SCR_PREDCT)
```

Solution  :-

```
solution : - x = [('PCT_ADLT_MALE', PCT_ADLT_MALE),('PCT_ADLT_FEM', PCT_ADLT_FEM)]

for a, b in x:
    Test[a] = Test[a].apply(b)
```

can anyone suggest me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` to run Python code in this environment.

Example:

```py
for key in Test.keys():
    eval( 'Test[' + key + '] = Test[' + key + '].apply(' + key + ')' )
```

---

Edit: If I misunderstood your example, you can take a look at this more general example:

```py
def test(x):
    print(x)

for i in range(3):
    eval('test(' + str(i) + ')')
```

and the second block (the for-loop) is equivalent to

```py
test(0)
test(1)
test(2)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: code is working fine but i just want to reduce the lines. right now i have 90 lines of code. can i do that with loop. it will pick one variable and respective def function.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Assuming all your functions are named by your keys, I'll update my ansewr

Comment: updated full code.. you can check. hoping that you will able to understand my problem. i just wat to reduce the lines

Comment: solution : - x = [('PCT_ADLT_MALE', PCT_ADLT_MALE),('PCT_ADLT_FEM', PCT_ADLT_FEM)]

for a, b in x:
    Test[a] = Test[a].apply(b)

Comment: @DeepakKumar Oh I finally understood. Can you take a look at my edit, it achieves the same purpose as your solution without using the `x` dictionary.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Did it help?

Comment: To some extend YES

Answer (score 0):

```
def PCT_ADLT_MALE(PCT_ADLT_MALE):
    pct_adult_male_data = [[0, 38], [39, 44], [45, 48]] #load this with as much as you need
    for value in pct_adult_male_data:
        if value[0] <= PCT_ADLT_MALE <= value[1]:
            label = f"B   {value[0]} --- {value[1]}"
            break
        else:
            label = "Q   <-1>   Uncoded"
            continue
    return label

print(PCT_ADLT_MALE(30))
```